# How to create the domain rule to remove prefix from Name domain in DQS

Tags: sql-server, data-quality-services

My source data contains a name and address column. So I have created 2 domain in DQS. My data is looking like

```
Name          Address
NSLIJ David   Adr1
NSLIJ John    Adr2
NSSSK Peter   Adr3
Dyanaa        Adr4
```

How can I create the domain rule on `Name`, like "if the name contains NSLIJ or NSSSK. We have to remove the that prefix from my name, so the result should be

```
Name    Address
David   Adr1
John    Adr2
Peter   Adr3
Dyanaa  Adr4
```

How we can achieve this Data Cleansing project in DQS?

Comment: please post the attemps you already made and the code you wrote.

Comment: I have used Term based relation In DQS. I gave The prefix which I dont want in the palce of value column and gave Null to 'Correct to Column'. It is working fine. If it is 2 or 3 Prefixes we can give explicitly. But If More number of Prefixes come, is there any Domain rules to achieve that.